# C++ constructor syntax explaination

Tags: c++, syntax, clang

I was going through [a tutorial for building an AST with the help of Clang/LLVM](http://amnoid.de/tmp/clangtut/tut.html).

I see this syntax there:

```
struct PPContext {
  // Takes ownership of client.
  PPContext(clang::DiagnosticClient* client = 0,
            const std::string& triple = LLVM_HOSTTRIPLE)
    : diagClient(client == 0?new clang::TextDiagnosticPrinter:client),
      diags(diagClient),
      target(clang::TargetInfo::CreateTargetInfo(triple)),
      headers(fm),
      pp(diags, opts, *target, sm, headers)
  {
    // Configure warnings to be similar to what command-line `clang` outputs
    // (see tut03).
    // XXX: move warning initialization to libDriver
    using namespace clang;
    diags.setDiagnosticMapping(diag::kind,diag::MAP_IGNORE);
//diag::warn_pp_undef_identifier was the initial value instead of diag::kind. But I changed since it gave error.
  }

  ~PPContext()
  {
    delete diagClient;
    delete target;
  }

  clang::DiagnosticClient* diagClient;
  clang::Diagnostic diags;
  clang::LangOptions opts;
  clang::TargetInfo* target;
  clang::SourceManager sm;
  clang::FileManager fm;
  clang::HeaderSearch headers;
  clang::Preprocessor pp;
};
```

And:

```
//What is the constructor doing here ? The construct looks very different and difficult to comprehend !!!
// Could someone break it up for me ?
PPContext(clang::DiagnosticClient* client = 0,
            const std::string& triple = LLVM_HOSTTRIPLE)
    : diagClient(client == 0?new clang::TextDiagnosticPrinter:client),
      diags(diagClient),
      target(clang::TargetInfo::CreateTargetInfo(triple)),
      headers(fm),
      pp(diags, opts, *target, sm, headers)
  {
    // Configure warnings to be similar to what command-line `clang` outputs
    // (see tut03).
    // XXX: move warning initialization to libDriver
    using namespace clang;
    diags.setDiagnosticMapping(diag::kind,diag::MAP_IGNORE);
//diag::warn_pp_undef_identifier was the initial value instead of diag::kind. But I changed since it gave error.
  }
```

Please let me know if there is any other material which would be of good help and learning experience. Thanks

Comment: what things confuse you specifically? default parameters? or A ? B : C expression? or something else?

Comment: The expression is PPContext(<expr>,<expr>) : (<expr>"5 times"). I am fine with the default parameters.  I am confused about what"() : () {//body of the constructor }". What does "():()" mean ?

Comment: Don't forget to mark a correct answer, if there isn't one, perhaps leave comments as to why you feel they aren't correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are constructor initializers.  They initialized class members with the value given to them.  For instance:

```
class TestClass
{
private:
    int someField;

public:
    TestClass() : someField(5) { }
};
```

Will initialize the member someField to have a value of 5 during the call to the TestClass() constructor.  You can separate multiple initializers with a `,` to initialize multiple members.  You can also pass parameters from the constructor to these initializers such as:

```
class TestClass
{
private:
    int someField;

public:
    TestClass(int _someField) : someField(_someField) { }
};
```

When this constructor is called, the value passed to _someField will be used to initialize someField.

Also consider inheritance.  Using the second `TestClass` as our base we get the following derived type:

```
class TestClassDerived : public TestClass
{
public:
    TestClassDerived(int _someField) : TestClass(_someField) { }
};
```

That's how you can construct a base class from a derived type and pass parameters to a non-default constructor.  Without this you wouldn't be able to construct the base with the appropriate parameters using a non-default constructor.

Comment: Before voting me down, please explain why you're doing so.  I would appreciate it, so I can fix whatever it was that I got voted down for.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a constructor initialization list, which is used for inheritance and initializating member variables.
Click [this link](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/) for a good explanation of this topic.

One scenario this is required is dealing with inheritance. Consider the following:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(int n)
    {
    }
};

class Derived : Base
{
public:
    // Error! How do we construct Base? We never pass n
    // to the constructor of Base.
    Derived(int n)
    {
    }
};
```

How can we change the above to compile? With a constructor initialization list:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(int n)
    {
    }
};

class Derived : Base
{
public:
    // Now your compiler is happy.
    Derived(int n) : Base(n)
    {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This constructur is in the format

```
PPContext(arg1, arg2)
    : initConstructor1,
      ...,
      initConstructor5
```

where you can exchange initConstructor to the initialization constructors of 
the PPContext members